# How to handle mysql #1062 - Duplicate entry error when creating a large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a table having around 5 million records. I'm loading records from a csv file.

There is a unique column, `url`.

While inserting, if the `url` is already in the table, I want to make a change in the new `url` value and then do the insertion.

**Example:**

- try inserting a record with a `url` of `"book"`.  If `"book"` already exists, the new record should have a `url` of `"book-1"` (then `"book-2"` and so on)
- result: the `url` values `"book-1","book-2"...` are in the table in addition to the initial value `book`

I have figured out that there are **2 ways** to do so.

1. before inserting each record: check whether the `url` value already exists; if it does then make the required changes in the new `url` value and insert.  I am afraid that this will result in a poor performance.
2. insert records without checking if the `url` value already exists.  If `url` value already exists handle the "mysql #1062 - Duplicate entry error" and make the required changes in the `url` value; retry the insertion.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: What will you be using to import the csv ? I would write a php file that would insert the records , use a try/catch block to get the 1064/1062 duplicate entry , and change the url accordingly.

Comment: I am writing a ruby script and using Sequel ORM.

Comment: Ruby isn't my field :) But i'm sure the same mechanism is there, run the query for each of the records in the CSV, if you get a duplicate-key exception, alter the value and insert it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an one-off problem, I'd like to recommend an ad-hoc MySQL solution:

1. If your table isn't MyISAM, convert to MyISAM.
2. Temporarily create an auto_increment integer column named
   `url_suffix`.
3. Temporarily delete the unique constraint on the `url` column.
4. Create the multiple-column index (`url`, `url_suffix`) and ensure that there are no other indexes that use `url_suffix`.
5. Insert all of your rows, allowing duplicate URLs. You'll notice that the auto_increment `url_suffix` column is keyed on the url now. So, the first particular `url` will have `url_suffix` of `1` and the next `2`, and so on.
6. Do an update like the following, then delete your temporary url_suffix column and put your unique constraint back.

Query to update all the rows:

```
UPDATE urls
SET url = if (url_suffix = 1, url, CONCAT(url, '-', url_suffix - 1))
```

In fact, you could skip step 6, keep the auto_increment field so you could easily add duplicate URLs in the future, and simply fetch your URLs like this:

```
SELECT (if (url_suffix = 1, url, CONCAT(url, '-', url_suffix - 1))) AS url
FROM urls
```

Your data would look something like this:

```
url     url_suffix
---------------------------
that    1
that    2
this    1
this    2
this    3
those   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem here that a simple trigger will prove inefficient when inserting due to the fact that you are saying they will go from 'book' to 'book-1' 'book-2' etc.   The easiest way to do this would be to have a new column which contains a numeric value defaulting to 0.   This could be done in a stored procedure i.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insertURL`(inURL VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
    DECLARE thisSuffix INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    // We have to get this ID first, as MySQL won't let you select from the table you are inserting to
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(url_suffix)+1,0) INTO thisSuffix FROM urls WHERE url_column = inURL;
    // Now the ID is retrieved, insert
    INSERT INTO urls (
        url_column,
        url_suffix
    ) VALUES (
        inURL,
        thisSuffix
    );
    // And then select the generated URL
    SELECT IF(thisSuffix>0,CONCAT(inURL,'-',thisSuffix),inURL) AS outURL;
END
```

Which is then invoked using

```
CALL insertURL('book');
```

And will then return 'book' if the suffix = 0, or 'book-1' if it's got a suffix greater than 0.

For purposes of testing my table design was

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
`url_column`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`url_suffix`  tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`url_column`, `url_suffix`)
);
```